# New article default status being set to trashed

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-article

I have an install of Joomla 2.5.3.
When I create a new article, the default STATUS field is set to "TRASHED".

Now I know that the ARTICLE.XML controls this, however it is not working. It does not matter what I set the default attribute to within the XML, it still remains as TRASHED.

I cannot find where in the code that this is getting generated.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Try updating to Joomla 2.5.8 first - the latest version. That might fix the problem!!

Comment: have you been editing any core Joomla files? If so, don't. and Try updating to Joomla 2.5.8 as George said.

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed a clean 2.5.3 copy and I cannot reproduce your problem.

I advise you to either:

- Reinstall 2.5.3 with a clean copy from [here](http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/16804/73116/Joomla_2.5.3-Stable-Full_Package.zip) (the same I used).
- Update to the newest 2.5 version (currently 2.5.8) which can be downloaded [here](http://www.joomla.org/download.html).

If in either case you want to preserve your content, you can use [Akeeba Backup](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606).